# gcc 4.8.4 "pragma GCC diagnostic not applied"

Tags: c++, gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

Using g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4

In a pre-compiled-header I have the following:

```
63 #pragma GCC diagnostic push
64 #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
65 #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
66 #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

Now when I go to run our build system, I get the following build error:

```
from <>../../../../Core_Pch.h:65,
    from <command-line>:0:
<>/../../../../external/include/BoostBase/boost/system/error_code.hpp: At global scope:
<>/../../../../external/include/BoostBase/boost/system/error_code.hpp:221:36: error: ‘boost::system::posix_category’ defined but not used [-Werror=unused-variable]
     static const error_category &  posix_category = generic_category();
```

There appears to be a possible bug already opened in GCC's [bug tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53431). However, I am wondering if anyone has this working? The bug eludes to the fact that the behavior of the preprocessor used by the **C** lexer works differently than that used by the C++ lexer.

---

This might be related to something else in our build system. Note that if I create the most simple of examples:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
int main(void)                               
{
  int x;                                     

  return 0;
}
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop
```

This works as expected if I invoke:

```
~/Devel/pragma $ gcc -Werror -Wall -pedantic main.c 
~/Devel/pragma $ g++ -Werror -Wall -pedantic main.c
```

Commenting out the ignored line results in:

```
mhoggan@mhoggan-Precision-T3600 ~/Devel/pragma $ gcc -Werror -Wall -pedantic main.c 
main.c:2:1: error: C++ style comments are not allowed in ISO C90 [-Werror]
 //#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
 ^
main.c:2:1: error: (this will be reported only once per input file) [-Werror]
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:5:7: error: unused variable ‘x’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
   int x;
       ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
mhoggan@mhoggan-Precision-T3600 ~/Devel/pragma $ g++ -Werror -Wall -pedantic main.c 
main.c: In function ‘int main()’:
main.c:5:7: error: unused variable ‘x’ [-Werror=unused-variable]
   int x;
       ^
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors
```

Comment: What if you turn off `-Werror`?

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of the other SO question linked on that bug thread?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Note that my question is, "I am wondering if anyone has this working?". Also he is asking with regards to 4.7, and I am asking with regards to 4.8.4. This bug might of been resolved. Note that the bug states it was in 4.8.0. So in theory its a follow up to see if anyone has the issue resolved in 4.8.4.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit turning off -Werror treats no warnings except for the ones I specify. Plus according to gcc's documentation, "Note that these pragmas override any command-line options." See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html

Comment: I know what `-Werror` does. I'm asking what its effect is on this bug.

Comment: The warning still appears, but the building still continues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86937/discussion-between-matthew-hoggan-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: I've got nothing else

Comment: [I can't reproduce the odd warning about C++ comments in C code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea5be257ea56d2c7).

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same warning on g++ 5.3.0. I've found a nasty solution by adding a dummy function under the definitions such as:

```
...
static const error_category & posix_category = generic_category();
static const error_category & errno_ecat     = generic_caregory();
static const error_category & native_ecat    = system_category();

inline void dummy()
{
    (void) posix_category;
    (void) errno_ecat;
    (void) native_ecat;
}
...
```